# How do you do a "hidden" field in Django's forms.Form models?

Tags: python, django, forms, hidden

```
lat = forms.FloatField()
```

How do you make this hidden?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
lat = forms.FloatField(widget=forms.HiddenInput())
```